# Random 50 entries on Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, filter, excel-formula

Hello I would like to create a random list of 50 from a set of data, but not have duplicates based off of a list that have already populated.

I am using:

```
=UNIQUE(INDEX(SORTBY(Data!A2:B5306,RANDARRAY(ROWS(Data!A2:B5306))),SEQUENCE(Data!D2),{1,2}))
```

But the 50 results will be pasted into another column to keep track of. I would like a formula that does not allow the 50 previous results to populate on the new 50 that would populate after refreshing.

I hope this makes sense.

I am trying to achieve a rolling list of entries that would be barred from populating.

As you can see in the snippet:
I would like to have the "list" randomly populate the "results", but not have the "completed results" populate the same data as the new refreshed "results".

Answer (score 2):

### Random Rows of Dataset

In cell `A2`

```
=TAKE(SORTBY(Data!A2:B11,RANDARRAY(ROWS(Data!A2:B11))),Data!D2)
```

In cell `D2`

```
=LET(rdata,Data!A2:B11,size,Data!D2,fdata,A2#,
    d,UNIQUE(VSTACK(rdata,fdata),,1),
    TAKE(SORTBY(d,RANDARRAY(ROWS(d))),size))
```

[image]

If you create your own `GetRandomRows` Lambda function using...

```
=LAMBDA(data,size,TAKE(SORTBY(data,RANDARRAY(ROWS(data))),size))
```

... in the *Name Manager*, you can utilize it with...

```
=GetRandomRows(Data!A2:B11,Data!D2)
```

... in cell `A2` and...

```
=GetRandomRows(UNIQUE(VSTACK(Data!A2:B11,A2#),,1),Data!D2)
```

... in cell `D2`.

Comment: Can you please explain to me how a lambda function works and how I can incorporate it into what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: You need to have MS365 for this to work. Copy the formula `=LAMBDA(...)`. Open the *Name Manager*. Enter a name e.g. `GetRandomRows` and in the bottom box paste the formula. Press `Ok`. Now you can use it anywhere in the workbook with e.g. `=GetRandomRows(Data!A2:B11,Data!D2)`. [Read the documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67).